# Ecommerce Tracking (Server-Side) - Batch Processing?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to use Ecommerce Tracking for my site, but my site isn't a traditional ecommerce type site.  We are a shipping company so our orders are based on shipping costs.

The way the website works is a customer on the frontend submits a box to process and then in the backend we calculate the shipping cost and then batch run all of our customers different shipments.

Is there a way I can use the Ecommerce Tracking code and have it loop on the backend through each shipment as I batch process all of them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with caveats (and only if you use Universal Analytics). If you [catch the client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) from the user session you can send the [transaction serverside via the measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom).

The caveat is that unless you send the data within a few minutes after the user has submitted the data the tracking session will have ended (tracking session lasts 30 min by default, altough you could adjust the value in the property settings), so your session count would be inflated and the transaction would not be attributed to the correct traffic source (but would probably end up as direct visits). You could try to [use the queue time parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) (which is intended for mobile apps that might be offline for time - it specifies and offset between the time an interaction occured and the time it was send to the server) which could potentially give you a time window of up to four hours (haven't tested that, though).

A simpler way would be to record the transaction and add the missing values by sending another transaction with the same transaction id - if you use the same id Analytics will add the new values to existing values. However internally this will still be recorded as two transactions, so various metrics (like conversion rates) will be wrong (there may be other side effects, I have never used this technique on a large scale).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So it looks like I'm probably best having my customer run this "ecommerce tracking" code from their account to avoid these session and duplicate transaction issues if I try to do this server-side on my backend?  The only issue with this is that the revenue won't be 100% accurate.  I'm not worried about tracking the "traffic source" I'm more concerned with tracking the "revenue" accurately; is there another method you see I can do server-side or should I just have the code trigger on the front end with my customers?